# deploying python flask project on azure using visual Studio

Tags: python, azure, deployment

I am having some trouble getting my Py project to be deployed on Azure.
The message I get is 
"The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Which I know is a config error in the project.
My web.config file has the below.

Python is installed in D in my azure web service and in C in my local machine
running Py2.7

Appname is whiteboard

port 5965 on local host...

What am I doing wrong?? MS documentation did not help

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="whiteboard.app"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
        <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
    </appSettings>
    <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
    <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor=" D:\home\Python27\python.exe|D:\home\Python27\wfastcgi.py"
        resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="C:\Python27\python.exe"
    arguments="F:\FYP-Whiteboard\Whiteboard\whiteboard\runserver.py %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%5"
    stdoutLogEnabled="true"
    stdoutLogFile="F:\FYP-Whiteboard\Whiteboard\whiteboard\LogFiles\python.log"
    startupTimeLimit="60"
    processesPerApplication="16">
    <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="SERVER_PORT" value="5965" />
        <environmentVariable name="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot" />
        <environmentVariable name="PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
    </environmentVariables>
    </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, your issue is resulted from the package missing or route error in `web.config`.(Or you could find log in `wfastcgi.log`) I did test successfully, please refer to my working steps:

As you found in the [Managing Python on Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service) , Azure App Service provide you with a `site extension`. You could install packages on `KUDU console`.

Step 1 : Create azure web app and add Extensions(here is Python 3.6.4 x64)

[image]

Step 2 : Publish your `flask` project and add the `web.config`.

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="<Your Project Name>.app"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\Python364x64\python.exe|D:\home\Python364x64\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Step 3: Switch to the Kudu CMD and commands `cd Python361x64` and `touch get-pip.py` and copy the content of the url `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` into the `get-pip.py` via Edit button, then run `python get-pip.py` to install the pip tool.

[image]

Step 4 : Install any packages you need via `python -m pip install Flask`

[image]

Hope it helps you. Any concern ,please let me know.

Comment: Yes I have done that already.The directory structure on the azure account has the python27 folder and the extension..

could you let me know what does the components httpplatform should contain?
in arguments and process path?
The location of the exe in the web directory(D there) or the loca(C drive in my machine)?